# Why isn't почтальо́н spelled почталён?

Tags: правописание, буква-ё

As far as I understand, the letter "ё" is used to write the same sound as "ьо" *only* when the corresponding "о" is stressed.

In почтальо́н we have "ьо" and the "о" is also stressed -- so isn't this the perfect place to write "ё" instead? Why is this not done? (In particular, what is the point of the letter "ё" if it is not used in all of the situations where it could be used? Why not just always write "ьо" instead?)

Comment: it's pronounced почталь-йон

Comment: @shabunc which is the same thing as почталь - ён, right?

Comment: @Chill2Macth - nope, it would be почталь-он in that case

Comment: pronunciation почталь-он without й is also possible, but sounds very archaic and pretensious

Comment: @Arioch to my knowledge it never was a case. Just like with медальон it was pronounced exactly that way since the time it was adopted

Comment: So, how are почталь-йон and почталь - он pronounced differently? In both cases the о is palatalized, so it sounds like a ё? Can someone link to an audio recording which clearly distinguishes the two? Whenever I try to palatalize a consonant by putting the tip of my tongue behind my lower two front teeth, I get the same sound as if I had just used a "y/й"-sound glide. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel

Comment: you perhaps can look for words "лён" or "клён" pronounced. They have the same syllable like last one in почтальон but with a vowel no-blending gap instead of soft-mark denoted pause. Like the famous old song http://pesnifilm.ru/load/devchata/staryj_klen_quot_devchata_quot/83-1-0-415

Comment: "how are почталь-йон and почталь - он pronounced differently" you seem to be mixing two concepts - spelling (writing) and pronunciation.
If you focus on sounds, then "почталь - он" is not possible. It is written like that, but pronounced it is "почталь-йон" because of softened Л, as I noted in my answer. The real dichotomy could have been between почтальон и "почталён". The latter would have sounded like лён/клён - loosing BOTH pause and "й" sound.

Comment: @Arioch So, there is blending of vowels in the soft-mark denoted pause? What is the difference between a vowel no-blending gap and a soft-mark denoted pause? I found audio recordings here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BD  but I don't hear the difference -- it sounds like all three have a й sound. The IPA is written differently though, for лён one has lʲɵn but for почтальон one has lʲjɵn --which I guess corresponds to the й you mention

Comment: кЛЁН sounded with no gap and no й, but blending of the vowel into a softened consonant. 
почтаЛЬОН is sounded with the gap, and because of the gap - with "й" sound. Yeah, it is mixed up a bit: on one hand, the softening of the consonant is "jumping over" the gap and softens "o" vowel into de facto "ё" (in sounding, not in writing!). One another hand, the gap makes the vowel "standing on its own" which forces й-prefixing. Indeed, rather convoluted scheme. One thing about learning or explaining languages, is noting quirks you never realized before :-D

Comment: That said, I still struggle to distinguish Holy and Holly spelling, or those three "a" sounds (American can't, British can't and (sorry) cunt). They really sound almost the same to me. What human being ever may want to differentiate them, really! :-D

Comment: @Arioch I didn't know that British can't is pronounced differently. But the difference between "cat" and "cut" is fairly pronounced -- the "a" sound in "cat" is very harsh and nasal, while the "u" in "cut" is very flat. That being said, people might reduce the harshness/nasalness of the "a" in "cat" sometimes in order to avoid coming off as obnoxious or uneducated see https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3246 see here for the pronunciation of "a" in "cat" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A6#Translingual -- although I never do that, I always use the "strong" pronunciation.

Comment: @Arioch A lot of the pronunciations for "cat" I found online don't use the (to me) correct vowel, instead of giving it its full harshness, they do weaken it somewhat so that it sounds more like the "u" in "cut" (this Wikipedia page gives a good pronunciation of the "u" in "cut" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel ) So basically if people trying to go out of their way to sound not obnoxious, they might blend the "a" sound in correctly-pronounced "cat" with the "u" sound in "cut" to get something in the middle when saying "cat" (according to the ELL answer above -- I never do that).

Comment: BTW, as far as I understand, the vowel of cAt is pronounced much like softened Russian a ( if you strip й from я, then the sound that you do long is somewhat different from plain "a" ). Except timings, `æ` in English is sounded longer than typical vowel for what I remember. W.r.t. "can't" in USSR schools were giving British English, so "can't" was one of exceptions to memorize. Along with -tre ending of French-derived nouns, etc. But trust me guys, you have WAY TOO MANY vowels :-D That led to fragmentation of "correct spellings" around the globe.

Comment: @Arioch That vowel "a" in "cat" is pronounced nothing like any Russian vowel. You are thinking again of the "u" in "cut", it seems. The clip I gave was sounded longer, but it is still the same sound, just shorter. See for example https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ash#Pronunciation I don't know about British english, but it's spoken by about 1/5 as many people as American English -- it's the equivalent of learning Ukrainian instead of Russian (since Kiev was the center of ancient Ruthenia, and the most variation in Eastern Slavic languages is found near their homeland, between Ukraine and Belarus)

Comment: @Arioch The essential idea is that the "u" in "cut" is so flat, that _any_/_all_ unstressed vowels will sound more like it than their stressed counterparts. As you already correctly noted, the exact same phenomenon occurs in Russian, although to an even greater extent than in English (as far as I am aware). If one mumbled, thereby not putting any clear stress on any syllable, it might sound almost as if every vowel was the "u" in "cut". Just like in Russian or German, if you want to know how to pronounce the vowels, start with the stressed/long versions, before considering the unstressed/short

Comment: versions. The correct pronunciation of the unstressed/short versions will follow naturally from the pronunciation of the stressed/long ones + laziness/mumbling (i.e. saying the stressed/long/strong versions in a lazy, slurring, mumbling manner will inevitably tend to have them go towards the unstressed versions, and thus towards the "u" in "cut" in sound, because it is such a flat/lazy vowel).This will work better in English than in Russian, because the difference between the stressed and unstressed versions is smaller, so less conscious effort to mumble/speak lazily is required for the effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "the same sound as "ьо"

No. There are separate, while in practice related, effects to be considered there:

1. short pause after the consonant before the vowel. The separation between two sounds. Prevention of blending.
2. softening of the consonant
3. softening of the vowel ( back "hard" vowels like `Ы` are matching front "soft" vowels like `И` )
4. prefixing the "soft" vowel sound with short "й" sound (iotation)

So, "hard mark" and "soft mark" (Ъ and Ь) primary purpose is #1 - making a pause.

Then, the "soft mark" also softens the consonant, unlike the "hard mark", but this does not remove the pause.

Now, the vowel pairs а/я, о/ё, э/е, ы/и, у/ю while primary are representing #3 typically have a consequences of effecting either #2 or #4.

When a "soft" vowel stands on its own or follows another vowel, then ё would sound more like йo. When following a consonant, the soft vowel blends in, softening the consonant, instead of prefixing its own sound with "й".
However both options #2 and #4 do NOT add the separating pause (#1), which is the hallmark of hard/soft marks.

All in all, почтальон is not pronounced as почталён, but as a почталь-pause-ён.
This pause makes putting the soft mark required.

---

Now, you may ask why isn't `почтальОн` then written as `почтальЁн` instead. Well, soft vowels are not typically written after soft sign. Hard vowel is written there traditionally, and it inherits its softness from the now softened consonant before it (despite being separated by a pause).

To contrast it, `ЛЁН` or `кЛЁН` are sounded with no gap and no `й`, but immediate blending of the vowel into a softened consonant `Л'`.

`почтаЛЬОН is` sounded with the gap, and because of the gap - with `й` sound. Yeah, it is mixed up a bit:

- on one hand, the process of softening the consonant is "jumping over" the gap and softens "o" vowel into de facto "ё" (in sounding, not in writing!).
- on another hand, the gap makes the vowel "standing on its own" which forces й-prefixing, like if the vowel would start the word or would follow another vowel.

Indeed, rather convoluted scheme. Gap is ignored for one process but is abided by for another.

It would stress the tongue a real lot to blend hard consonant sound with following soft vowel sound, or soft consonant with a hard vowel. It just does not work out without injecting a separating pause (which in turn would effect soft vowels to regain their Й sound prefix).

---

Pronunciation samples of syllables with separating pause and with blending..

"Кто там? Почта**льон** Печкин"

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1cOuYb40ac
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lx6gUVTSPBU

"Старый к**лён**, старый к**лён**, старый к**лён** стучит в окно"

- http://pesnifilm.ru/load/devchata/staryj_klen_quot_devchata_quot/83-1-0-415

Comment: I thought the primary purpose of the soft signs was to just soften the consonant, which is aurally nearly indistinguishable from prefixing the vowel with a short й sound. So I don't yet understand how they are different. In making the short й sound/softened consonant isn't one forced to make a short pause anyway? I mean obviously I am wrong here somehow, my point being please explain to me where I am wrong.

Comment: in `лён` there is no `й` sound inside. There is softened consonant `л'` immediately blending into the vowel sound `o`. When two letters, consonant and vowel, are just written together - there is neither pause nor "й", only softened blending.

Comment: Or put it another way, the primary reason d'etre for soft mark is softening consonants where there is no vowel to do it. In many cases you may imagine soft mark being like a softening nil vowel. Vowel without sound. Before 1917 all the consonant-ending nouns had to be finished with either hard or soft mark. After 1917 hard mark was made default and omitted. Consider ел/ель. There is no vowel past the end of the word, so one has to put soft mark instead to distinguish those two words.

Comment: Could you perhaps link to an audio recording which clearly distinguishes й-glides from vowels prefixed by palatalized consonants? Whenever I try to palatalize a consonant by putting the tip of my tongue behind my lower two front teeth, I get the same sound for the following vowel as if I had just used a "y/й"-sound glide. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel  It's even more confusing to me since I thought that й was a soft vowel, thus it must necessary palatalize the preceding vowel, e.g. хлеб sounds the same as хлйеб.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, й is the palatal approximant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant (just like "y" in English) -- so I don't know how to differentiate it from palatalized vowels. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)#Slavic_languages  Also especially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotation Iotation is a distinct phenomenon from Slavic first palatalization in which only the front vowels are involved, but the final result is similar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_first_palatalization

Comment: Й is called "short I" - "И краткое". Like @Quassnoi told in his answer, historically it derived from shortened diphthongs like "-ие". And in Bulgaria they still have "short Ы" sound, that in Russian got totally reduced to "hard mark" denoted pause. So, indeed, one can see Й as a semi-vowel.

Comment: @Chill2Macht: there is no such thing as a palatalized vowel: if your tongue is pressed against your palate, you can't produce a vowel at all. What there is in Russian is non-palatalized (hard) and palatalized (soft) consonants (think *л / ль*) and also back and front vowels (think German *Mutter / Mütter*). Now, a back vowel cannot follow a soft consonant (no *ль-у*, not without a hiatus between the sounds); nether a front vowel can follow a hard consonant (no *под-играть*, also without a hiatus).

Comment: If you see some of this in writing, this means that either the consonant is soft (*миг*), or there is an epenthetic *[j]* between them (*почтальон*) or there's a hiatus (*контригра*) or something. What exactly it is is something you'd have to figure out separately, but those two rules above is just how Russian phonetics works.

Comment: @Quassnoi personally I still pronounce контр-pause-ыгра. Just like with почтальон - the hardness/softness of the consonant sound "jumps over the gap" and get inherited by the vowel sound.

Comment: @Arioch: yeah, *контригра* is a bad example. In *почтальон*, though, nothing gets "inherited": you just insert a *[j]* (a soft consonant) between the consonant and the vowel.

Comment: @Quassnoi it gets, still. The vowel sound turns into front vowel, the same as in "лЁн". It lacks the Й indeed, but the longing sound itself is definitely softened, if comparing with plain back vowel of stand-alone O like in панталОны. Just keep the last vowel sound longing for few seconds in уклОн и клЁн and you obviously hear the difference. Same there with почтальон pronounced with ё not o in both censes (presenсe of Й and "frontalizing" the sound)

Comment: @Arioch: oh do you mean the -о- changing its quality (compared to, say, *биатлон*)? That's exactly what I was trying to say with my comment: if the writing suggests a back vowel follows a soft consonant, then something definitely sounds not the way it's written (in this case, it's both the epenthetic *[j]* and the vowel changing to a front one).

Comment: @Arioch - `soft vowels are not typically written after soft sign` - Are you sure??? What about _семья, семьи, семье, семью, пью, лью, бью, воробьи, муравьи_ and the like?

Comment: @YellowSky okay, standard words endings are exception. I meant when inside the same word part

Answer (score 5):

The sounds *[ɵ]/[jɵ]*, which are now denoted by the letter *ё*, were not present in Church Slavonic and a letter to denote them was not there in Cyrillic before late XVIII century.

By the time it was introduced there had already been a tradition of conveying *[jɵ]* as *iо* or, rarely, *ьо* (after consonants) in loanwords.

Native Russian words which feature those sounds have emerged from Slavic words with *[ɛ]/[jɛ]*: *житьё < житие, питьё < питие* etc., so they use the newly created letter *ё* which was deliberately made "backwards compatible" with the Church Slavonic letter.

Transcription systems which have emerged after the introduction of *ё* and don't have to rely on tradition do sometimes use *ё*: *Eyjafjallajökull > Эйяфьядлайёкюдль, 吉原 (Yoshiwara) > Ёсивара, 연평도 (Yeonpyeongdo) > Ёнпхёндо* etc.

Russian phonetics does not allow a back vowel (*а, у, ы, э, о*) after a soft consonant, so this distinction between *ьо/йо* and *ьё/ё* is purely traditional.

Comment: OK, so the idea being that почтальон is too old of a word to be spelled with ё? (I.e. it was present in Russian before the late XVIII century?). What was the Church Slavonic letter you refer to? Also, is there a phonetic difference between ьо and йо? That seems to be the idea behind other answers/comments (that почтальон is pronounced почталь - йон but почталён would be pronounced почталь-ьон) but it is very difficult for me as a foreigner to understand the phonetic difference between palatalized and iotated vowels.

Comment: @Chill2Macht: yes. Couldn't find *почтальон* attested before the introduction of _ё_, but *батальон* and *медальон* used to be *баталiонъ* and *медалiонъ* back then. The Church Slavonic letter was *е /  є / ѥ* (there were some subtle differences in usage of the three but for the purpose of this question it's easier to think of them as the same letter). _-льо-_ and _-лё-_ differ as English "good year" and "good ear" do: the latter does not have a *[j]* in it. *-льо-* in *почтальон* and *-льё-* in *польёт* don't differ at all, not in the slightest.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it would still be pronounced the same if written почтальён, but NOT if written почталён?

Comment: @Chill2Macht: exactly.

Answer (score 5):

**почтальон** is pronounced [поч'тал'й'он]

**почталён** would be pronounced [поч'тал'он] which is different.

**почтальён** would be pronounced the same way as **почтальон**. The reason why it is not spelled this way is because the letter ё is usually avoided in foreign words. The reason possibly is that the ё is often spelled without diacritics, as е, so this may create a confusion on how to pronounce the word (not with this word of course but as a general rule). The word came from German *Postilion*, from French *postillon*, from Italian *postiglione*.

Comment: another interesting thing is how middle S was first transformed to SH and then to CH :-)

Comment: @Arioch: through Polish, apparently.

Comment: Also because ё is simply a modification of the letter е and exists only in places where a stressed е would historically be pronounced. For this reason, it also alternates heavily with е, and also for this reason the diacritic is often dropped ─ as, morphologically, е and ё are the same letter, just with different phonetic realistions. So putting ё in place of etymological о's would be misleading and abusive of the letter's purpose.